# Android Camera orientation, phone gives false data?

Tags: android, camera, orientation, samsung-mobile

I'm using the code from Android camera docs:

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```

In portrait mode one of my phones (Samsung GT-S5660) reports info.orientation as 0 and display rotation 0 which makes the preview go in landscape mode. On another phone(HTC) this works like it should. HTC reports info.orientation as 90 in this case. If I set display orientation manually to 90 it works on Samsung too.

So the question is: does the Samsung give false information or am I doing something wrong?