# Camerainfo.orientation gives wrong answer

Tags: android, android-camera

Android provides [this code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29) to make a camera preview appear face-up for all camera and screen orientations:

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```

In the simplest case, when the screen is face-up in portrait (`rotation` is 0) with a back-facing camera, this reduces to `result = info.orientation`.  According to the docs, info.orientation is

> the angle that the camera image needs to be rotated
>   clockwise so it shows correctly on the display in its natural
>   orientation. It should be 0, 90, 180, or 270.

This means that `info.orientation` should be the amount the raw images from the camera are rotated *counter-clockwise*.

On a Samsung Galaxy S II's back-facing camera, `info.orientation` is 90, as expected for back-facing cameras.  However, the raw camera preview is rotated 90 degrees clockwise, not counter-clockwise.  This means that after applying the above code, the preview appears upside-down (180 degrees).

**Why is there a 180 degree discrepancy between the camera's reported orientation and the actual orientation of its raw images?**

This exact problem - camera images being 90 degrees clockwise when `info.orientation` reports 90 - has also been reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055460/is-androids-camerainfo-orientation-correctly-documented-incorrectly-implemente) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103070/is-the-setdisplayorientation-sample-code-correct?rq=1).

Also see [this possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135166/android-camera-orientation-phone-gives-false-data).